# How to attach the camera to a player object instantiated by HLAPI Network Manager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In short, I have a very simple multiplayer game. It's the Roll A Ball game (Unity3D tutorial). So right now I have the players etc spawning perfectly and everyone is able to control their own balls perfectly fine.

But here's the problem: I've got a default Main Camera. Since it's only the local player itself that needs to see it, I figured there's no point in trying to spawn a seperate camera for each player on the server.

However, to make the camera follow the player, I need to attach it the player gameobject. Obviously I can't attach it to the player prefab as it's a clone the camera needs to follow. But since the player is being spawned by the Network Manager component, I have no idea on how to refer to this clone.

What I've tried myself:

```
public class CameraController : NetworkManager
{

    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public Transform target;

    private Vector3 offset;

    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        GameObject player = (GameObject)Instantiate(playerPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        target = player.transform;
        NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player, playerControllerId);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

But this resulted in:
[image: Screenshot of Error]

Which I find extremely odd since as you can clearly see, there's no NetworkIdentity component on the NetworkManager object. I've been trying A LOT of things for the past 4 hours now and I just can't do it. So now I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Edit: This is how the Network Manager normally spawns a player. As you can see, there's no code for it:

[image: Network manager player spawn]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a camera to the prefab and then write a player script like this:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;

    void Awake()
    {
        if(!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            camera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting approach. Lemme see what I can do with that. I'll let you know!

Comment: I've tried but the camera isn't spawning at all. At first I got the error that camera wasn't attached to an object. It did spawn, just remained stationary. So I attached the camera. Error gone, but it no longer spawned at all, haha. Obviously again because the attached camera is a prefab I guess..

Comment: Hmm console tells me if(!isLocalPlayer) returns true.. obviously the reason why there's no camera.. weird

Comment: When I remove the check, the camera spawns and follows the player. Unfortunetely the camera will always follow the latest player that joins the game for everyone. So now it's a matter of figuring out why it's not seeing the player object as localPlayer.

Comment: Thanks to your help I've finally managed to get it to work. Therefor I'm accepting your answer as I think you've deserved some extra credit for it. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @icecub And how did you solve it exactly? What was your issue?

Comment: Check his answer below ;)

Comment: @JeromeJ It's been way to long for me to remember any of this. I've stopped developing in Unity for quite some time now. But like Rafiwui said, you can check my own answer to this question. There I'm showing what I've done to fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and figured out the followig solution. Seems like you already got a solution, but maybe it is interesting to share some possible ways for other people in the same situation.

This is a way to do it without a camera attached to the prefabs.

I'm using a NetworkManager to instantiate Player-prefabs. (Same as you)

I solved the problem of finding references to the clone objects by letting the clones tell the camera, who they are (or which transform belongs to them).

The Player has the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour {



public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
{
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
    Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().target=transform; //Fix camera on "me"

}

void Update ()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer) 
    {
        return;
    }
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
    var z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

    transform.Rotate (0, x, 0);
    transform.Translate (0,0,z);

}
}
```

On my default main Camera (there is no camera attached to the player prefab, just the default camera) I put the following script on. It takes a target which I initialised with the prefab using the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target; //what to follow
public float smoothing = 5f; //camera speed

Vector3 offset;

void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position,  targetCamPos,smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

After starting the game, each clone tells the camera who he is, so the target changes to the individual clients clone with this line from the Player's Script:

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().target=transform; //Fix camera on "me"
```

This way you don't need to create one camera per instance of player-prefabs (I'm not sure if this makes big differences in performance) and you don't have to deactivate all cameras which don't belong to your client.

If you host the game in the editor you can see that there is just 1 camera instead of one camera per connected client (like when you attach it to the prefab).

I think this is a good use of this method, you can use it to put things in it, which should be applied to the Local Player only.

```
public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
{ 
}
```

I tried by starting the game in the editor and in a build and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I've not really worked with networking but what if you do this after you spawn the local player

```
Camera.main.transfor.SetParent(the transform of the local player here);
```

As I understand the problem each separate instance of the game has a main camera.

Comment: You understand correctly. But to be able to do this, you need a refference to the player clone object. Which doesn't exist by default. The player is only spawned after he joins ofc. Normally the Network Manager just spawns the player, but there's no refference to it. That's why I override the components player spawn and do it myself so I have this refference `GameObject player`.

Comment: @icecub so after you call instantiate why cant you set the camera.main pos to the player pos, parent the cam to  the player object that is instantiated and apply a offset ?

Comment: Because that's the exact problem. The Network Manager component does the instantiate internally. There's no code for it. Hence the override, which results in the problem above. I've updated the question with a screenshot of how it works by default. Perhaps that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. Apperently you create a Network Manager by doing this, which caused 2 Network Managers to be in the scene. So my idea to override it was stupid in the first place

Comment: @icecub i was going to suggest that maybe you had two scris deriving from network behaviour. But the question remains how to do what you want. After reading the unity doc this seems viable.

Comment: I know. It's really frustrating me a lot. I don't mind wrapping up the project into a rar for you so you can download it and take a look for yourself if that helps? :)

Comment: [http://www.icecub.nl/BasicMultiplayerShooter.rar](http://www.icecub.nl/BasicMultiplayerShooter.rar) Just in case

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rafiwui's point into the right direction, I've finally managed to get it working. All I had to do was adept his code a bit. The end result was:

```
public Camera camera;

void Awake()
{
    camera.enabled = false;
}

public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
{
    camera.enabled = true;
}
```

Thanks A LOT to you all for helping me out! This has been quite a day for me.